# converting the *.lm to *.dmp file for building the language model for speech recognation

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am getting the below given error while executing the command `sudo sphinx_lm_convert -i 9055.lm -o 9055.dmp`.

```
sphinx_lm_convert: error while loading shared libraries: libsphinxbase.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I dont understand the reason. Please help.

Answer (score 5):

This error means that system fails to find the shared library in the location where it is installed. Most likely you installed it with default prefix /usr/local/lib which is not included into the library search path. You can fix it in the following ways:

- Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to point to the location where sphinxbase is installed (usually /usr/local/lib)
- Modify /etc/ld.so.conf in order to include /usr/local/lib
- Compile and install sphinxbase with /usr prefix instead of /usr/local/lib

To learn more about shared libraries and the system-wide configuration please read about dynamic libraries:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html